# Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path") returns a different value in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm having some trouble with an Oracle client running in ASP.NET web application. After some checks I found that the problem could be the fact that `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path")` returns a wrong value.

If I call the method in a console application it returns the correct value. If I call it in the ASP.NET web application it returns another (wrong) value, that I'm not able to find in system properties or in Windows Registry.

My ASP.NET application is running under Local IIS and the AppPool identity is set to my User (that is the same that runs the console application).

To confirm that I checked the following properties on the two applications and the values are the same:

- `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`
- `Environment.UserName`

I tried looking at the source code of `GetEnvironmentVariable`, but it basically wraps a call to the **Win32** method `GetEnvironmentVariable` (which source code is "obviously" unavailable).

What am I missing?

After some checks, I noticed that even the value I get in the console application is different by the ones I found there:

[image: System Properties]

So what is the "source" of GetEnvironmentVariable?

[Microsoft says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms682653(v=vs.85).aspx) that the process environment variables are loaded from the parent process, so I checked w3wp.exe process hierarchy. It is the following:

wininit.exe -> services.exe -> svchost.exe -> w3wp.exe

wininit, services and svchost run as SYSTEM.

wininit and services Path environment variable contains the value that I can find in System Properties ("System environment variables"). `svchost` has a different value, so (probably) the cause of the difference between the value I get in console application and the one I get in the ASP.NET web application is the fact that `svchost` edits this value.

Comment: I would respectfully request clarification on what you mean by "the wrong value." The environment is what the environment is; perhaps it is returning the environment for a user/process context other than that which you are predicting. Could you expand on why you think it is "wrong?"

Comment: @DavidW With "wrong" I meant that it is different by value configured (from system properties), but after the latest update, it seems that even the value I get in the console app is different by these value

Answer (score 0):

I believe you changed the `"Path"` and haven't restarted your IIS. `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` would return the value for current process. If the current process hasn't restarted then it will not see the modified value.

So, restart IIS and then you will get the value.

You can restart the process in GUI or go to command prompt and execute `iisreset`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I didn't run `SetEnvironmentVariable` method. I also tried `AppPool` recycle, kill `w3wp.exe` process and `iisreset`, but `GetEnvironmentVariable` still returns the wrong value.
I also tried rebooting PC....

Comment: @codroipo, strange, Go to command prompt and type `Path`, see what you get, may be the value is not set properly. Make sure that the actual Path value in operating system is the one you are looking for

Comment: Running `Path` in command prompt returns the correct value (the one that I get with the Console Application)

Comment: After comparing every single case I noticed that the `Path` returned in command prompt differs by one character from the one that I get in the Console Application (but basically they are different). What could that mean?

Comment: @codroipo, well that character would probably be ending semi colon, which will be ignored, don't worry about that. Make sure that you don't have any call to `SetEnvironmentVariable` in your ASP.Net app. Do a code search. This seems really odd.

Comment: The character is in the string, the string I get in console application is `BLABLABLA;C:\Program Files (x86)BLABLABLA`, the one I get in command prompt is `BLABLABLA;C:\ProgramFiles (x86)BLABLABLA`. The difference is in ProgramFiles, one time is `Program Files` and the other is `ProgramFiles`. This led me to think that the values are read from different source

Comment: @codroipo, one last thing, try `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
` may be the path in your configuration is based on different users.

Comment: `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)` is different by the one I get from the command prompt and also different by the one I get from `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path")`